# How to add a frame or divider each item of navigation drawer?

Tags: android, layout, styles, navigation-drawer, frame

I want to customize my navigation drawer items like [image: this]

My navigation view like this ;

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

items are like [image: this]

I just wonder that how to add frame or divider? Do I need to set a custom layout to my navigation drawer or what ? If you want some more info let me know. 
Please help me thanks..

Comment: you want to add a border or a frame after each menu. Then you need to create a custom menu.Let me know if you want to create a custom menu

Comment: I asked to find out if there's a shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom border drawable.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **app:itemBackground="@drawable/customer_border"**
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

inside navigation menu